# Expose provider to app.config and controller

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to expose the provider `mobileSettings` to my config and MainController. Currently the below setup returns the following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module adsomaApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: mobileSettings
```

**app.js**

```
angular
  .module('adsomaApp', [
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch'
  ])
  .provider('mobileSettings', function() {
    var $this = this;

    this.isNotMobile = (function () {
      var check = false;
      (function (a) {
        if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) { check = true; }
      })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
      return !check;
    })();

    this.$get = function() {
      return $this;
    };
  })
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, mobileSettings) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: (mobileSettings.isNotMobile) ? 'views/main.html' : 'views/main_mobile.html',
        controller: 'MainController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
      })

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });   
  });
```

**MainController**

```
angular.module('adsomaApp')
  .controller('MainController', function (mobileSettings) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.isNotMobile = mobileSettings.isNotMobile;    
});
```

How do I go about fixing it? I'm not sure how to inject mobileSettings into my `.config` and MainController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two injectors in AngularJS application, for config and run phases respectively. The former operates on service providers, the latter operates on service instances.

It is `mobileSettingsProvider` service provider and `mobileSettings` service instance.

It should be injected to `config` block as `mobileSettingsProvider`. This will work, but only because `mobileSettingsProvider === mobileSettings` for this particular service.

A service that doesn't have dependencies and should be used during both config and run phases is a use case for `constant` service type (which is primarily intended for all sorts of constants, as the name suggests):

```
.constant('mobileSettings', { isNotMobile: (function () { ... })() })
```

`constant` is the only service type that defines no separate service provider. It should be injected as `mobileSettings` everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the "Provider" suffix because it is a config phase injection

```
        .config(function (..., mobileSettingsProvider){
            ...
        });
```